# Remove a specific commit but keep all the commits afterward

Tags: git, version-control

I do manage git in an organized way, as per my knowledge. I commit every specific changes, so that I can get back to a single bit of feature whenever I want. In this process, I've added a feature (commit #`74fd458`) about 10 days ago, where I added a binary file and made changes in 3 tracked files.

After that I made at least 15 commits.

> `dfs4334` - new commit 15
>   `2yu44m6` - new commit 14
>   ...
>   `47jc063` - new commit 1
>   **`74fd458` - Target Commit (seems unwanted now)**
>   `560dfsf` - old commit 1
>   `lfg956d` - old commit 2
>   ...

Now I came to a situation that, that specific commit (read 'feature') is unnecessary. So, thing is very simple, open a commit visualizer and remove those specific lines made in that specific commit, remove that binary file that's added then, and you are done. But, you know it's messy.

**Q:** Is there any way I can keep all the changes I made afterward, but remove, or revert, or pick a specific commit out of the branch?

---

<sup>**PS.** As scenario can change anytime, that specific feature can be added later. So I don't want to remove that feature completely from version control, I just put those things out, but to keep them somewhere so that I can merge them anytime, if necessary.</sup>

Comment: Have you get the answer what you want? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT thank you for your reminder. I know that and am well aware about doing so. But currently I's aside from that specific task. Will implement it on next available time inshALLAH and will surely mark the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way I can keep all the changes I made afterward, but remove, or revert, or pick a specific commit out of the branch?

[`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) is probably what you are looking for.
From the documentation:

> Revert some existing commits
>
> Given one or more existing commits, revert the changes that the related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record them

In your case, both the original commit and the (let me say) *revert commit* will be part of the project's history.
You can revert the *revert commit* later if you need it, that is if you need to apply the original commit once more.

See the linked documentation for further details.

Comment: Just ran `git revert 74fd458` and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: YES!!! all the rebase etc ones are not what I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a way to remove a specific commit and keep afterward commits:

1. Checkout to the branch and use `git rebase -i HEAD~16`
2. There is an interactive window shows the latest commits (`74fd458` on the top and newest `dfs4334` on the bottom).
3. Input `i` and delete the commit you want to remove (`pick 74fd458`)
4. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> button and then input `:wq`

So the commit `74fd458` will be removed.

**Note:** If there has conflict, you should use `git add <filename>` and `git rebase --continue`

Comment: The OP doesn't want to remove this commit from version control, so a rebase isn't appropriate in that case